# Codename One UWP app local machine server HTTP issue

Tags: uwp, codenameone

I cannot get my Codename One UWP app to communicate via HTTP to a server running on the same machine. The app works in the simulator connecting to localhost and I can connect to my machine on its LAN IP when it is running on a real Android device. I found a similar issue here:

https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2056

And added the windows.capabilities build hint. Unfortunately communication still fails the same way. My AppxManifest.xml file contains the following:

```
<Capabilities>
  <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer"/>
  <Capability Name="internetClient"/>
  <uap:Capability Name="picturesLibrary"/>
  <uap:Capability Name="videosLibrary"/>
  <uap:Capability Name="removableStorage"/>
  <uap:Capability Name="musicLibrary"/>
</Capabilities>
```

The error in the stacktrace is the same as in the link above (Message=An error occurred while sending the request. The text associated with this error code could not be found. ... A connection with the server could not be established). The server never receives the request.

I have tried connecting to "127.0.0.1", "localhost" and all of my LAN IP addresses.

I have created a test program that shows the problem. To test, run a program to capture traffic sent to a port (http://www.linklogger.com/portpeeker.htm on Windows works). Now try to connect to it using your LAN IP.

```
import java.io.*;
import com.codename1.io.*;
import com.codename1.ui.*;
import com.codename1.ui.events.ActionEvent;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BoxLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager;

public class LocalServerTest {
    private final StringBuffer logContents = new StringBuffer();

    private volatile TextArea logTextArea;

    public void init(Object context) {
        Log.install(new Log() {
            @Override
            protected Writer createWriter() throws IOException {
                return new Writer() {
                    @Override
                    public void write(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException {
                        logContents.append(new String(cbuf, off, len));
                        if (logTextArea != null) {
                            Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
                                logTextArea.setText(logContents.toString());
                                logTextArea.getParent().revalidate();
                            });
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void flush() throws IOException {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void close() throws IOException {
                    }
                };
            }
        });

        UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");
    }

    public void start() {
        logTextArea = new TextArea(logContents.toString());
        logTextArea.setRows(40);

        NetworkManager.getInstance().setTimeout(5 * 1000);

        Form hi = new Form("Test local server connection", BoxLayout.y());
        TextField ipAndPortField = new TextField("", "IP:port");
        hi.add(ipAndPortField);
        hi.add(new Button(new Command("Test") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                ConnectionRequest request = new ConnectionRequest() {
                    @Override
                    protected void buildRequestBody(OutputStream os) throws IOException {
                        os.write(new String("Some test data").getBytes("utf-8"));
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void handleException(Exception err) {
                        Log.p("Could not communicate with server", Log.ERROR);
                        Log.e(err);
                    }
                };
                request.setUrl("http://" + ipAndPortField.getText() + "/test");
                request.setPost(true);
                request.setFailSilently(true);
                request.setTimeout(5 * 1000);
                request.setSilentRetryCount(0);
                request.setCookiesEnabled(false);
                request.setContentType("text/plain");
                request.addResponseCodeListener(e -> {
                    Log.p("Response code received: " + e.getMessage(), Log.INFO);
                });
                request.addResponseListener(e -> {
                    Log.p("Response received: " + e.getMessage(), Log.INFO);
                });
                Log.p("Sending request to " + request.getUrl(), Log.INFO);
                NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(request);
            }
        }));
        hi.add(logTextArea);
        hi.show();
    }

    public void stop() {
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it the same server as you are running on?
Are you using HTTPS?

Comment: Did you mean that the local server is another server machine in your internal network?

Comment: Thanks for the comments @ShaiAlmog and Xavier. I have done some further testing and the problem only occurs when I connect to my local machine. It works if the server is on a separate machine on my LAN. I have updated the question to make this clear.

Comment: The connection is via HTTP, not HTTPS.

Comment: I'm looking into this.  I can confirm, at least, that the lack of a `uap:` prefix is correct.  I.e. Your AppxManifest.xml file looks correct.

Comment: @RussHayward Have you tried to type the address in webbrowser directly to see if you can send request successfully?

Comment: @stevehannah - thank you for looking into it - glad that part is okay. :)

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT: Yes I have tried that thanks. GET doesn't work on the URL so the browser shows a 500 error, but I can POST using Postman to the URL with "localhost", "127.0.0.1" or my LAN IP as the host and they all work.

Comment: @RussHayward Have you tried to enable the 'Enterprise Authencation' in Package.manifest? Sometime, it will work, but I'm not sure if your issue is related to this capability.

Comment: I just built a simple test case to verify that connecting to localhost should work.  I'm just running the php development server on a directory of my Windows 10 box, and a simple test Cn1 client. It seems to work, although I had to step through a few issues with Windows firewall (e.g. allow connections to php).  I suggest trying to make the problem smaller.  Create a simple test server using either the php dev server, or another simple, shareable solution - and create a simple Cn1 test case.  If your test case works, then you're closer to a solution.  If not, you can share the test case.

Comment: @stevehannah: Sorry for the delay, took a while to get time to write a test program - I have added it to the question.